# How to rename a dynamically created macro?

Tags: pstricks, programming, pst-plot

I can use `\let` to rename

- `\curvepnodes` to  `\ParametricNodes`,
- `\Pnodecount` to `\LastIndexP` as follows.

However, because `\Pnodecount` is generated dynamically inside `\curvepnodes`, I cannot move `\let\LastIndexP\Pnodecount` to the preamble or to a separate file.

```
\documentclass[pstricks]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot}

\let\ParametricNodes\curvepnodes

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(-1,-1.5)(7,1.5)
    \ParametricNodes[plotpoints=50]{0}{2 Pi mul}{t|sin(t)}{P}
    \let\LastIndexP\Pnodecount
    \foreach \i in {0,...,\LastIndexP}{\psline(P\i|0,0)(P\i)}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

## Question

How to rename a dynamically created macro `\Pnodecount` in the preamble or a separate file?

Note: The `P` in `\Pnodecount` is the node name specified in the last argument of `\curvepnodes`.

## Edit 1

The objective is to have more intuitive names for both macros mentioned above. It does not matter what kind of methods you use to accomplish this issue, whether using patching, hijacking, injecting, renaming, copying, etc as long as I can do the patching, hijacking, injecting, renaming, copying, etc in the preamble or a separate file.

## Edit 2

I am not interested in manual labor by writing

```
\def\LastIndexA{\Anodecount}
```

in the preamble after I use `\curvepnodes...{A}` in the body because  renaming will be done automatically in a separate file (my own package).

Comment: your question isn't very clear, the dynamic aspect doesn't seem very relevant?  even if `\PnodeCount` was a fixed name, it is locally defined just within each pspicture, so you clearly can not use the `\let` to make an alternative name outside the scope where the original command is defined?

Comment: \let doesn't rename commands, it create copies. You are perhaps looking for `\def\LastIndexP{\Pnodecount}`.

Comment: And, did you try if \def solves your problem?

Comment: Well it works fine for me. So again, did you **try**, and if yes, what doesn't work as expected?

Comment: Well then define `\ParametricNodes` so that it defines the \lastindex-command too with \csname.

Comment: You accepted my answer but did you want `\LastIndexP` to be `\csname LastIndex#4\expandafter\endcsname` (if so just make that substitution in the definition in my answer)

Comment: Sorry you probably didn't delete the preceding expandafter, I edited my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a command being defined by some code and you want it to define a different name in addition to the one it is defining, you need to change the code making the definition. In this case:

```
\documentclass[pstricks]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot}

\makeatletter
\let\curvepnodes@i@old\curvepnodes@i
\def\curvepnodes@i#1#2#3#4{%
  \curvepnodes@i@old{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}%
  \expandafter\let\csname LastIndex#4\expandafter\endcsname
                  \csname#4nodecount\endcsname
  \ignorespaces}
\makeatother

\let\ParametricNodes\curvepnodes

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(-1,-1.5)(7,1.5)
    \ParametricNodes[plotpoints=50]{0}{2 Pi mul}{t|sin(t)}{P}
    \foreach \i in {0,...,\LastIndexP}{\psline(P\i|0,0)(P\i)}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @ArtificialStupidity not easily as there are all kinds of `*`-forms and optional arguments to be parsed over so you need to drop down to a level where they have been resolved.

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass[pstricks]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot}

\let\ParametricNodes\curvepnodes
\def\LastIndexP{\Pnodecount}

\begin{document}
    \begin{pspicture}(-1,-1.5)(7,1.5)
    \ParametricNodes[plotpoints=50]{0}{2 Pi mul}{t|sin(t)}{P}
    \foreach \i in {0,...,\LastIndexP}{\psline(P\i|0,0)(P\i)}
    \end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It is not the solution that I want to achieve because it is impractical.

Comment: `\let\ParametricNodes\curvepnodes
\makeatletter\let\LastIndexP\psk@plotpoints\makeatother` should also work

Answer (score 1):

Since you need to know the affix at call time anyway, the simplest solution is to use a one argument macro.

```
% arara: latex
% arara: dvips
% arara: ps2pdf

\documentclass[pstricks]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot}

\let\ParametricNodes\curvepnodes
\newcommand*{\LastIndex}[1]{\csname #1nodecount\endcsname}

\begin{document}
% original syntax
\begin{pspicture}(-1,-1.5)(7,1.5)
    \curvepnodes[plotpoints=50]{0}{2 Pi mul}{t|sin(t)}{P}
    \foreach \i in {0,...,\Pnodecount}{\psline(P\i|0,0)(P\i)}
\end{pspicture}
% "better" syntax
\begin{pspicture}(-1,-1.5)(7,1.5)
    \ParametricNodes[plotpoints=50]{0}{2 Pi mul}{t|sin(t)}{P}
    \foreach \i in {0,...,\LastIndex{P}}{\psline(P\i|0,0)(P\i)}
\end{pspicture}
% with a different name
\begin{pspicture}(-1,-1.5)(7,1.5)
    \ParametricNodes[plotpoints=50]{0}{2 Pi mul}{t|sin(t)}{Q}
    \foreach \i in {0,...,\LastIndex{Q}}{\psline(Q\i|0,0)(Q\i)}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]